# Unable going a level up on directory

Tags: php

I need to store a temporary image on an upper directory from the one that the file is placed. I know the `../` method, but it this case it does not work:

```
<?php
if((!empty($_FILES["img"])) && ($_FILES['img']['error'] == 0)) {
  $filename = basename($_FILES['img']['name']);
  $ext = substr($filename, strrpos($filename, '.') + 1);
  if (($ext == "jpg") || ($ext == "jpeg") || ($ext == "png") || ($ext == "gif") && ($_FILES["img"]["type"] == "image/jpeg") || ($_FILES["img"]["type"] == "image/png") || ($_FILES["img"]["type"] == "image/gif") && 
    ($_FILES["img"]["size"] < 300000)) {

    //HERE IS WHERE I SET THE FINAL DIRECTORY

      $newname = dirname(__FILE__).'../temp/'.time();

      if (!file_exists($newname)) {
        if ((move_uploaded_file($_FILES['img']['tmp_name'],$newname.'.'.$ext))) {
           echo "Hecho! Guardada como: ".$newname;
        } else {
           echo "Error: Se produjo un problema durante la subida".$newname;
        }
      } else {
         echo "Error: El archivo ".$_FILES["img"]["name"]." ya existe";
      }
  } else {
     echo "Error: Tamaño máximo excedido (300kb) o formato erróneo (jpg, png, gif)";
  }
} else {
 echo "Error: No existe el archivo";
}
?>
```

Having the `dirname(__FILE__)` before does not let me set properly the directory, as it tries to find `/var/www/html/panel/actions../temp/1430671269.jpg`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this code:

```
dirname(__FILE__).'../temp/'.time();
```

produces this result:

```
/var/www/html/panel/actions../temp/1430671269.jpg
```

Then it likely follows that *this* code:

```
dirname(__FILE__).'/../temp/'.time();
```

would produce *this* result:

```
/var/www/html/panel/actions/../temp/1430671269.jpg
```

Which, if you want to go up one directory, should do the trick.

Basically, if you need to add a slash to the string, then add a slash to the string.

Comment: Thank you. I'll tick in 5 minutes.